# The upper half plane as a hermitian manifold

Tags: number-theory, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am reading about [Shimura Varieties](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/svi.pdf) and I am at odds with some of the claims being made (I realize this problem really has nothing to do with number theory, but perhaps some number theorists have come across this). Here are the definitions that I am working with:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold.
>
> 1. A *riemannian metric* on $M$ is a smooth 2-tensor field $g$ such that $$g_{p} : T_{p} M \times T_{p}M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ is symmetric and positive definite for all $p$.
> 2. An *almost-complex structure* on $M$ is a smooth tensor field $J = (J_{p})_{p \in M}$ $$ J_{p} : T_{p}M \rightarrow T_{p}M$$ such that $J^2 = -1$ for all $p \in M$. If $M$ is a complex manifold and $z^1 , \dots , z^n$ are local coordinates about $p$ and $x^1 , \dots , x^n , y^1, \dots, y^n$ are the corresponding real coordinates, then $J_{p}$ acts by $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j} \quad \text{ and } \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j} \mapsto -\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$$
> 3. A *hermitian metric* on a complex (or almost complex) manifold $M$ is a riemannian metric $g$ such that $$ g(JX , JY) = g(X , Y) \quad \text{for all vector fields } X , Y.$$ A *hermitian manifold* $(M , g)$ is a complex manifold $M$ with a hermitian metric $g$.

My problem is that the notes claim that the complex upper half plane $\mathcal{H}$ becomes a hermitian manifold (among other things) when endowed with the metric $g: = \frac{dxdy}{y^2}$.

While $g$ is certainly symmetric, my calculations show that $g$ is not positive definite; I have worked it out a few different ways, but maybe the easiest way to see this is that the matrix representation of $g$ with respect to the basis $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right\}$ is $$ [g] = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2y^2} \\ \frac{1}{2y^2} & 0  \end{pmatrix},$$ which is certainly not positive definite. Also I am getting that $g(JX, JY) = - g(X, Y)$ for $X,Y$ vector fields on $\mathcal{H}$.

I can outline my calculations if necessary, but is anything I have stated incorrect? I am assuming that $dxdy$ is denoting the symmetric product of $dx$ and $dy$, i.e. $dxdy = \frac{1}{2} ( dx \otimes dy + dy \otimes dy)$, perhaps the notation is indicating something else?

Comment: Dear @Oiler, I have been reading the same paper as you do, and got confused at the same example. Although I understand now that there has been a typo, I do not see how the metric $g: = \frac{dxdy}{y^2}$ is symmetric. If my understanding is correct, given a point $p$ in the upper half plane with imaginary part $y$, and two tangent vectors $z_1$, $z_2$ with coordinates respectively $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ in the basis $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right\}$, we would have $g(z_1,z_2)=\frac{x_1y_2}{y^2}$, that is not symmetric. Am I confused with the notations?

Comment: @Suzet Are we in agreement with the matrix representation of $g$ that I have listed above? Because if we are then $g(z_{1} , z_{2}) = \begin{pmatrix} x_{1} & y_{1} \end{pmatrix} [ g] \begin{pmatrix} x_{2} \\ y_{2} \end{pmatrix} = \frac{x_{1} y_{2} + y_{1}x_{2}}{2y^2}$ and $g(z_{2} , z_{1}) = \begin{pmatrix} x_{2} & y_{2} \end{pmatrix} [ g] \begin{pmatrix} x_{1} \\ y_{1} \end{pmatrix} = \frac{x_{1} y_{2} + y_{1}x_{2}}{2y^2}$. So $g$ is indeed symmetric as written (but is not positive definite).

Comment: Given your matrix, I agree with your computations. However I believe (and I may be wrong) that his matrix represents the metric $g'=\frac{dxdy + dydx}{2y^2}$, at least as far as I understand it. That is different from the starting metric $g$, as $dxdy = dx\otimes dy \not = dy \otimes dx=dydx$.

Comment: @Suzet $dx dy$ is the symmetric product of $dx$ and $dy$. So $dx dy = \frac{1}{2} (dx \otimes dy + dy \otimes dx)$.

Comment: Then that is alright with me if it is just a matter of definition. I am just surprized as the author of the paper writes on page 6 as a footnote "we usually write $dx^idx^j$ for $dx^i\otimes dx^j$". In any case it does not matter much provided that we all understand the meaning of the notions. Thanks for your reply! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in those notes. The metric should be given by
$$\frac{dx\otimes dx + dy\otimes dy}{y^2}.$$ In complex coordinates this can be written as $\dfrac{|dz|^2}{y^2} = \dfrac{dz\otimes d\bar z + d\bar z\otimes dz}{2y^2}$. 
I suspect that they're writing down the Kähler form (which should be a $(1,1)$-form, and not a symmetric tensor) associated to the hermitian metric.

Comment: I suspected that this was the intended metric, but thanks for confirming.